# Writing tasks in Meteor

Tags: meteor, gruntjs, gulp

I'm starting to develop applications in Meteor and I've some questions about Build System.

Is it possible create my own build tasks as in gulp and grunt ?

I've tried to use Meteor Build System, but It was deprecated in Meteor 1.2 (July 2015).

Reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/CompileStep-API-for-Build-Plugin-Source-Handlers

For example:

`gulp start-android
gulp publish --env (beta|stable)
gulp docs`

Comment: Did you look at https://www.meteor.com/isobuild ?

Comment: Sorry, I've used the IsoBuild to build (Android .APK) and package(tar.gz).

I would like to have freedom to writing my own tasks and automate routines ex: (Continuous Integration, Database seeding and Running Tests).

This question it's important to me because I didn't see examples.

Could you help me ?

Comment: I do not have any experience with Isobuild, but you can look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580077/does-meteor-need-either-gulp-or-grunt to get an answer. gl hf ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have several dev tasks, such as unit testing, decryption of api keys from secure storage, deploying meteor to multiple environments, ect, running as NPM scripts. Combining NPM scripts with bashjs and/or python and you can run any tasks or pre-building activities for Meteor or other Node builds.

If you wanted to do something more advanced, please provide a context what you would want to change in the current building process...